# Is it possible to transmit a decoder's UI over Wifi instead of using an HDMI cable?

Tags: television

I have a problem that I don't really know how to solve (I mean, I know how to solve it in an ugly way but I'd prefer a cool one :))

Premise: I'm using Unitymedia, a German Internet, TV and phone (the last two over internet) provider. They sent me the Horizon HD[1], a big box which does everything. Data connection is made over a cable, specifically this[2] one.

I only have one internet plug, which is downstairs. For space reasons, I want to have the TV upstairs. But this means that:

1. I have to buy a 20mt data cable, for connecting the plug to the Horizon HD which will be upstairs. (Ugly solution)
2. I have to...what? :-)

   - I was thinking about connecting the data plug to the Horizon HD downstairs and then plug into the decoder an HDMI-WiFi (like a miracast or something similar) stick. Do you think it is possible to transmit the decoder UI over WiFi? Or am I forced to connect the HDMI cable to the TV?
   - sub-problem: how can I change channels if the TV is upstairs and the decoder downstairs? :-(
   - I connect the data plug downstairs to a small WiFi router, then I'd connect the Horizon HD to this WiFi router. Again, do you think it is possible?
   - please, tell me what you would do :-)

[1] https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_08_I38TOu8/maxresdefault.jpg

[2] http://www.antennenland.net/bilder/produkte/gross/Horizon-Kabel-Cabelcon-10m.jpg

Comment: What is the highest resolution offered by the box or viewable on your tv? Also what type of bandwidth does your internet have? These will play a big factor.

Comment: @norcaljohnny I have a 130 Mbit downstream and 6 Mbit upstream via ethernet (which is the max I can get according to my contract :))
My TV has a 4k resolution and the box offers a 1080p max res.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a Home Improvement question so much as a networking and device question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about connecting two pieces of consumer electronics, not about Home Improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use WiFi, you can use a specific transmission system.  These are known as videosenders or digisenders.  I use a German made system for sending the signal from my Sky satellite box to the television in the bedroom.

They are available in the 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands.  For the HD that you require I suggest that you would need to use the 5GHz variant.  You will also need to ensure that the version you buy has suitable input connections for the feed that you can provide.

All videosenders have a backchannel for sending signals from the remote control to the box downstairs.

They are quite common in the UK, there is some information [here](http://www.radioandtelly.co.uk/videosenders.html) but it refers mostly to the 2.4GHz variety.

Comment: I definitely owe you more than one beer :D This one[1] seems to suit my needs :)
[1] MARMITEK GIGAVIEW 820 HD WIRELESS SENDER KIT

Answer (score 0):

**The general solution**

Get two pieces of hardware:

1. A standard wifi router
2. A wifi extender with an ethernet port (I like the Netgear N300)

This is fairly cost effective and it gets you a few multi-tasking tools. The wifi router gives you wireless internet throughout your home. The extender acts as a wireless-to-wired bridge to service your TV decoder.

**The cheapest and most direct solution**

Buy the 20m ethernet cable and just run it and be done with the job. Running a cable properly isn't hard, isn't expensive, and this will give you the best connection to the TV decoder